# String to Float Convert with decimal point Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `String` with decimal points of value. When I convert the `String` value to `Float` like this

```kotlin
val i : String = "123.70"
val j  = i.toFloat()
Log.e("Tag", "-->" + j)
```

the result printed is

```
Tag-->123.7
```

But, what I want is

```
Tag-->123.70
```

Is there any possible way to get my desired result?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `String` that takes a decimal and formats it to a specific amount of decimal places.

Example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // you have a String with a decimal value
    val i : String = "123.70"
    // then you parse/convert it to a Float
    val j : Float = i.toFloat()
    // and then, you output the value of the Float in a specific format
    println("%.2f".format(j))
}
```

This prints

```
123.70
```

which should be working in the LogCat as well:

```kotlin
Log.e("Tag", "-->%.2f".format(j))
```

Comment: your answer will be String but i need Float value.. i don`t want tag.. i want to store in variable like which one i declared  "val  j"

Comment: @pushparajkannan you already have that `Float` value, but in your `Log` it is displayed without trailing zeros... I thought that was clear to you... You can format that `Float` with a (nearly) arbitrary amount of trailing zeros, but the value inside the `val j` will stay the same.

Comment: yes, my `val i` values should  like what i declared.. because i get that values from `"%.2f" ` format... after i got that i stored in `val i`. in my case, i want the `val i` values in `Float` format.. when i convert `String` to `Float`, last 0 was trimed

Comment: @pushparajkannan that's happening when you don't specify a format. Trailing zeros will be cut off for brevity, I think.

Answer (score 1):

internally it doesn't affect it is the same but if you want to show it as 2 decimal places you can use String.format("%.2f", number).

```
val number = 10.7086134
val rounded = String.format("%.3f", number) // rounds to 3 decimal places
```